# Question on how to use the axiom of choice in an extension problem

Tags: logic, axiom-of-choice

I am in doubt about the proper use of the axiom of choice
I use extension theorem that says that “there exists” a function with a property, call it property A.
Then, I am wondering if I can use the axiom of choice to pick all such extensions, my understanding of the axiom of choice is that I can do that, but am I missing something?
More detail:
I am working on a problem related to the representation of a binary order by means of a collection of utility functions. So I am using a result that guarantees that there exists some utility functions that guarantee that for any 4 points, $x,y,\hat{x},\hat{y}$ in $X$ such that $(x,y)\in R$, and $(\hat{x},\hat{y})\in \lnot R$, where $R$ is the binary relation in question and $\lnot R$ is the complement of $R$ in $X\times X$; **there exists** a utility function such that $u(x)\geq u(y)$ and $u(\hat{y})>u(\hat{x})$. So that's all good, but then I want to make sure I can **select** all such extensions, so I need to build a set that contains all such extensions for each $(\hat{x},\hat{y})\in \lnot R$.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are asking exactly?

Comment: sure, I added more detail

Comment: If you want to get *all* such extensions the issue is not just the axiom of choice but rather whether you risk getting a class instead of a set.  You have to limit somehow what you mean by "all" to make sure that the collection is not too "big" and therefore will be a set.

Comment: Thanks this is a good hint, I see, so my issue is that I can get a class that is a collection larger than any set, so I have to put some restrictions on the size, ok not sure how to do this, so I may have to switch to a constructive proof

Comment: Mikhail Katz, in my case wouldn't it suffice to show that my collection of all such extensions is an element of the set of continuous and monotone functions? in that case I have a set no?

Comment: If you can make sure the entire construction takes place in a suitable stage in the [superstructure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_(mathematics)#In_ordinary_mathematics) that would be enough.

Comment: thanks a lot Mikhail Katz this is definitely helpful, albeit I have to delve more into superstructures, I am hopeful because of the additional structure and I will keep thinking of a more constructive proof.

Comment: You probably don't really need the full superstructure, if everything can be fit into $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(X))$ or something.